# YU Yureka stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, unbricking

I have a **Yu Yureka plus**.i tried installing twrp and it got into bootloop.fastboot didnt detect my device and i gave to a repair center.after 5 days,they sent back my device saying it cant be repaired.i cant go to fastboot mode nor recovery mode.whatever combination of buttons i press,i goes to a screen which says **Download Failed Images-aboot**ihow can i get back to recovery now.i am blank.please guide.

Comment: What does the device manager shows when you connect the phone to the computer?

Comment: @esQmo the device manages identifies it as adb interface

Comment: adb interfaces ? what is the output of `adb devices` or `fastboot devices`

Comment: @esQmo ,Thank You for the concern, adb shows no devices while fastboot shows blank.actually fastboot shown in google images is very much different from the fastboot in my device(volume up+put usb in).there is no text of fastboot there,so that is why i mentioned the device is not going to fastboot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use its full fastboot command

```
fastboot -i 0x1ebf devices
```

Or any other command with `fastboot -i 0x1ebf`.

This will definitely work in Yureka.